# How to merge word and excel Office 365 Proplus from powerbuilder 12.5 application

Tags: office365, powerbuilder

i have a problem when trying to merge a word to excel through powerbuilder 12.5 application.

The below code is working fine in earlier versions of Office... But not in Office 365 Proplus..

Have a look, and if someone have a suggestion please dont hesitate,, any reply would be really appreciated!!

The code for the Microsoft Office transactions...

```
if ll_systemPrintouts = iuo_tools.MS_OFFICE then

oleobject iole_word
long ll_Error
iole_word = CREATE oleobject
ll_Error = iole_word.ConnectToNewobject("word.application")

CHOOSE CASE ll_Error
    CASE -1, -2, -3, -4, -9, -15, -16
        word_exception luo_exception
        luo_exception.setmessage ( "The application cannot connects with Word" )
        luo_exception.setexplain ( "Code Error: " + String ( ll_Error ) )
        Throw luo_exception
END CHOOSE

iole_word.Documents.Open( ls_path )

iole_word.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = 0 
iole_word.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource( ls_DataSourceFile,0,false,false,false,false,"","",false, &
                    "", "", "Entire Spreadsheet", "SELECT * FROM 'Sheet1$'", "", false, 8)
iole_word.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Destination = 0
iole_word.Application.Visible = abl_visible

return iole_word 

else
.....
```

Bear in mind that the applications crashes on , **ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource**

Please guys i m so stack in this point and dont know what to do :(

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked in the Office 365 documentation to make sure the OpenDataSource method still accepts the parameters you are sending?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Matt Balent, the only documentation for this method that i can find on the net is for office 2003 and is the following passing 16 parameters like my code.. with the following description,

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220319(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: cant find for office 365... :(

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.mailmerge.opendatasource.aspx, this says for 2013 and later.

Comment: Thank you Kateract for the reply :)